# What was the cost of the 2,500 year celebration of the Persian Empire

Tags: iran

Wikipedia says, [The Celebration of the Persian Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,500_year_celebration_of_the_Persian_Empire)

> The Ministry of the Court placed the cost at $17 million (at that time); Ansari, one of the organizers, puts it at $22 million (at that time).[7] The actual figure is difficult to calculate exactly and is a partisan issue, but may have exceeded $200 million.[citation needed]

What was the cost of the party? I see the celebration often cited as a source of discord at the time.